# How can I aquire data that a user selected on dependent spinner?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, spinner

### What I would like to do

I would like to acquire data that the user selected on dependent spinners.

On my current code, it was succeeded to acquire the data from the first spinner but I cannot do it from the second spinner.

### Problem

How should I fix my code to acquire appropriate data of a user's selection?

1. In this case, the second textView should be BMW but it is Audi, which is the first candidate of the second spinner.

[image: motor]

2. The first textView is changed following a user's selection. In this case, it changed to mobile from motor, but again, the second textView was remained as the first the first candidate of the second spinner.

[image: mobile]

### Current Code

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.spinner

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    var spinner1: Spinner? = null
    var spinner2: Spinner? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1) as Spinner
        spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2) as Spinner
        val adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.array1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )
        spinner1?.setAdapter(adapter1)
        spinner1?.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)
    }
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the main; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        val id = item.getItemId()
        return if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            true
        } else super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(
        parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int,
        id: Long
    ) {
        if (spinner1?.getSelectedItem() == "mobile") {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext, "Mobil dipilih",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()

            val adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.mobile_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
            )
            spinner2?.setAdapter(adapter2)
            spinner2?.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)

        } else {
            val adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.motor_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
            )
            spinner2?.setAdapter(adapter2)
            spinner2?.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)

        }


        // here I try to put the selected contents to variables
        val spinner1_content = spinner1?.getSelectedItem() as String
        textView1.text = spinner1_content
        val spinner2_content = spinner2?.getSelectedItem() as String
        textView2.text = spinner2_content


    }


    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.stackspinner.MainActivity" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#00f"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#00f"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```xml
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Application Name</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string-array name="array1">
        <item>mobile</item>
        <item>motor</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="mobile_array">
        <item>Android</item>
        <item>blackberry</item>
        <item>apple</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="motor_array">
        <item>Audi</item>
        <item>BMW</item>
        <item>unicorn</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

#### current code after hearing an answer

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.spinner

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    var spinner1: Spinner? = null
    var spinner2: Spinner? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1) as Spinner
        spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2) as Spinner
        val adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.array1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )
        spinner1?.setAdapter(adapter1)
        spinner1?.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)

        val adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.array1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )
        spinner2?.setAdapter(adapter2)
        spinner2?.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)
    }
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the main; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        val id = item.getItemId()
        return if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            true
        } else super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(
        parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int,
        id: Long
    ) {
        if (spinner1?.getSelectedItem() == "mobile") {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext, "Mobil dipilih",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()

            val adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.mobile_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
            )
            spinner2?.setAdapter(adapter2)

        } else {
            val adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.motor_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
            )
            spinner2?.setAdapter(adapter2)

        }


        // here I try to put the selected contents to variables
        val spinner1_content = spinner1?.getSelectedItem() as String
        textView1.text = spinner1_content
        val spinner2_content = spinner2?.getSelectedItem() as String
        textView2.text = spinner2_content


    }


    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You never added an adapter or listener to `spinner2` in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you explain its detail with a code? I can see the change of spinner2 depends on selected spinner1, and user can select each element on spinner2.

Comment: Nowhere in your code did you call `spinner2?.setOnItemSelectedListener`, so nothing will happen when you select items in `spinner2`.

Comment: I've changed MainActivity.kt with `spinner2?.setOnItemSelectedListener` but in this case, when I change the first spinner, the app was shut down on the emulator and the textView of secound spinner didn't changed either.

Comment: The stack trace will tell you why it's crashing. As for your logic, since both spinners are using the same listener, you need to distinguish which one just got changed by using the value of `parent`. Like `when(parent) { spinner1 -> { /* logic for spinner 1 */ } spinner2 -> { /* logic for spinner2 */ } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take note that every time you select a mobile (o a motor) you recreate your spinner2. You should use different listeners for each spinner:

```
spinner1.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
              //your spinner1 listener code
            }

        }
```

spinner2.dothesame.....

I put the entire onCreate for better understanding:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1) as Spinner
    spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2) as Spinner
    textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1) as TextView
    textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2) as TextView

    val adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.array1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    )
    spinner1?.setAdapter(adapter1)
    spinner1?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {


            var spinner2Adapter: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>? = null
            //select the right adapter for de Spinner2
            if (spinner1?.getSelectedItem() == "mobile") {
                spinner2Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                        applicationContext,
                        R.array.mobile_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
                )
            } else {
                spinner2Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                        applicationContext,
                        R.array.motor_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
                )
            }
            //set the adapter and the listener for spinner2
            spinner2?.setAdapter(spinner2Adapter)
            spinner2?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

                }

                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    val spinner2_content = spinner2?.getSelectedItem() as String
                    textView2?.text = spinner2_content

                }
            }


            // here I try to put the selected contents to variables
            val spinner1_content = spinner1?.getSelectedItem() as String
            textView1?.text = spinner1_content
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still it is not clear where I can implement it. I have uploaded my current code but it doesn't work. Could you post the code include both before and after the each lister implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explaint it well. In the onCreate method replace 
 `spinner1?.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)` with the code that I put. And set the spinner2 listener in the same way. You dont need anymore the function onItemSelected

Comment: Thank you for additional information. I update my current code following your explanation but in this case, the app didn't start (automatically shutdowns) on the emulator.

Comment: ```    
        val adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.array1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )
        spinner2?.setAdapter(adapter2)
        spinner2?.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain with code which include before and after the `spinner1.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` statement?